# Oracle WMS GetFeatureInfo issue with points and lines

Tags: wms, oracle-spatial, getfeatureinfo, configurable-map-viewer

I am trying to do GetFeatureInfo request on MVDEMO sample data.
When it comes to polygons, it is working fine:

[image]

When I do the same type of requests on lines or points, I get an empty response:

[image]

As you can see, no attributes are returned. Any ideas why is that a case?

The attributes are enabled in MapBuilder:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your GetFeatureInfo request does not hit on any line or point feature.

Comment: `When I do the same type of requests on lines or points, I get an empty response` how do you generate the requests?